Retrieving the key of an inserted entity in a generic way
In an existing project we are using linq2db as ORM and we are massively using the DataConnection.InsertWithIdentityAsync which based on the Entity primary key retrieves the key.
As far as I've seen in EF Core to do in a generic way the best approach is to use something as
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static int AddEntity<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
        var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
        var primaryKey = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
        var keyProperty = primaryKey.Properties.FirstOrDefault();
        if (keyProperty != null)
        {
            return (int)keyProperty.PropertyInfo.GetValue(entity);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No primary key found for entity.");
    }
}

Is there any build-in method that for sure will be more optimized than this one?
We are doing so normally when managing a DB change:

we use FluentMigrator to generate the migration
We scaffold using linq2db cli.

Another possibility would be to define an Interface IIdentity and manually generate the partial class that inherits from its specific type. but we must add a partial class every time we add or modify a table/table index.
Any suggestion?

more optimized -- What is not optimal in the current code? Also, why do you need this? It sounds like an XY problem.
